# Can ES6 remove the need for frameworks?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Double binding = Object.observe()
Templates = es6 templates... up to a point
Dependency injection = import/export
Routing = ?

Comment: `Object.observe` is ES7.

Comment: Even the most fully-featured languages still have a myriad of frameworks... I guess this is to be expected in order to provide some boilerplate code for different design patterns. Take for example the MVC pattern... There will still need to be some reusable framework that defines Models, Views, and Controllers and their functionality. *However*, ES6 should reduce the need to resort to syntactic hacks in order to replicate some of these patterns, e.g `class Model { create() {} }` vs. `jQuery.extend({ Model: function(){ function create() }})` or some other hack to simulate the behavior we want.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You might have to use *fewer* *library* functions, because the language provides the same functionality natively.

*Frameworks* however provide higher level application organization and functionality (think Backbone or express).